# Kill children when the parent is killed

Tags: perl, fork

Is there an easy way for Perl to kill child processes when the parent is killed? When I run `kill` on a parent PID the children stay alive.

Test script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

@sleeps = qw( 60 70 80 );
@pids   = ();

foreach $sleeptime (@sleeps) {

    my $pid = fork();

    if ( not defined $pid ) {
        die;
    }
    elsif ( $pid == 0 ) {

        #child
        system("sleep $sleeptime");
        exit;
    }
    else {

        #parent
        push @pids, $pid;
    }
}

foreach $pid (@pids) {
    waitpid( $pid, 0 );
}
```

Comment: Note that `exec("sleep", $sleeptime) or die;` would be far simpler than `system("sleep $sleeptime"); exit;`. It would reduce the number of processes in your example from 10 to 4.

Comment: sounds like you want to kill a process group, not just a process

Comment: @ikegami, I count 7 processes, rather than 10, as each fork() + system() adds two processes ([system() bypassing the shell in this case](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html)), but the point is well taken.

Comment: @pilcrow, oh yeah, forgot about the optimization you mentioned.

Comment: Please always tidy and indent your code and `use strict` and `use warnings 'all'`, on Perl programs that you're asking for help with. You're asking for free help, and I think the least you could do is to make your code readable. I've done it for you this time; please think again in the future

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Note**   The second example, using `END` block, is more complete.
**Note**   Discussion of how to use the *process group* for this is at the end.

---

Most of the time chances are that you are dealing with `SIGTERM` signal. For this you can arrange to clean up child processes, via a handler. There are signals that *cannot* be trapped, notably `SIGKILL` and `SIGSTOP`. For those you'd have to go to the OS, per answer by [Kaz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1250772/kaz).  Here is a sketch for others. Also see other code below it, comments below that, and *process group* use at the end.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw(say);
say "Parent pid: $$";

$SIG{TERM} = \&handle_signal;  # Same for others that can (and should) be handled

END { say "In END block ..." }

my @kids;
for (1..4) {
    push @kids, fork;
    if ($kids[-1] == 0) { exec 'sleep 20' }
}
say "Started processes: @kids";
sleep 30;   

sub handle_signal { 
    my $signame = shift;
    say "Got $signame. Clean up child processes.";
    clean_up_kids(@kids);
    die "Die-ing for $signame signal";
};

sub clean_up_kids { 
    say "\tSending TERM to processes @_";
    my $cnt = kill 'TERM', @_;  
    say "\tNumber of processes signaled: $cnt";
    waitpid $_, 0 for @_;  # blocking
}
```

When I run this as `signals.pl &` and then [kill](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/kill.html) it, it prints

```
[13] 4974
Parent pid: 4974
Started processes: 4978 4979 4980 4982
prompt> kill 4974
Got TERM. Clean up child processes.
        Sending TERM to processes 4978 4979 4980 4982
        Number of processes signaled: 4
Die-ing for TERM signal at signals.pl line 25.
In END block ...

[13]   Exit 4                        signals.pl
```

The processes do get killed, checked by `ps aux | egrep '[s]leep'` before and after `kill`.

By courtesy of `die` the `END` block gets executed orderly so you can clean up child processes there. That way you are also protected against uncaught `die`.  So you'd use the handler merely to ensure that the `END` block cleanup happens.

```
use POSIX "sys_wait_h";
$SIG{CHLD} = sub { while (waitpid(-1, WNOHANG) > 0) { } };  # non-blocking
$SIG{TERM} = \&handle_signal;

END { 
    clean_up_kids(@kids);
    my @live = grep { kill 0, $_ } @kids;
    warn "Processes @live still running" if @live;
}

sub clean_up_kids { 
    my $cnt = kill 'TERM', @_;
    say "Signaled $cnt processes.";
}
sub handle_signal { die "Die-ing for " . shift }
```

Here we reap (all) terminated child processes in a `SIGCHLD` handler, see [Signals in perlipc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html#Signals) and [waitpid](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/waitpid.html). We also check in the end whether they are all gone (and reaped).

The `kill 0, $pid` returns true even if the child is a zombie (exited but not reaped), and this may happen in tests as the parent checks *right* after. Add `sleep 1` after `clean_up_kids()` if needed.

Some notes. This is nowhere near to a full list of things to consider. Along with mentioned (and other) Perl docs also see UNIX and C documentation as Perl's ipc is built directly over UNIX system tools.

- Practically all error checking is omitted here. Please add
- Waiting for particular processes is blocking so if some weren't terminated the program will hang. The non-blocking `waitpid` has another caveat, see linked `perlipc` docs
- Child processes may have exited before the parent was killed. The `kill 'TERM'` sends `SIGTERM` but this doesn't ensure that the child terminates. Processes may or may not be there
- Signal handlers may get invalidated in the `END` phase, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40688429/perl-signal-handlers-are-reset-in-end-blocks/40691964#40691964). In my tests the `CHLD` is still handled here but if this is a problem re-install the handler, as in the linked answer
- There are modules for various aspects of this. See [sigtrap](http://perldoc.perl.org/sigtrap.html) pragma for example
- One is well advised to not do much in signal handlers
- There is a lot going on and errors can have unexpected and far ranging consequences

---

If you `kill` the *process group* you won't have any of these issues, since all children are then terminated as well.  On my system this can be done at the terminal by

```
prompt> kill -s TERM -pid
```

You may have to use a numeric signal, generally `15` for `TERM`, see `man kill` on your system. The `-pid` stands for the process group, signified by the minus sign. The number is the same as the process ID, but add `say getpgrp;` to the code to see. If this process has not been simply launched by the shell, but say from another script, it will belong to its parent's process group, and so will its children. Then you need to set its own process group first, which its children will inherit, and then you can `kill` *that* process group. See [setpgrp](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/setpgrp.html) and [getpgrp](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/getpgrp.html).

Answer (score 3):

This is something that has to be done at the operating system in order to be reliable. Linux has a `prctl` (process control) system call which multiplexes numerous functions, similarly to `ioctl`. One of the functions (opcode `PR_SET_PDEATHSIG`) arranges for a process to receive a specific signal (passed as the second argument) when its parent dies.

There is a [CPAN module](http://search.cpan.org/~seveas/Linux-Prctl-1.3.1/lib/Linux/Prctl.pm) wrapping up `prctl` where this appears as a [`set_pdeathsig`](http://search.cpan.org/~seveas/Linux-Prctl-1.3.1/lib/Linux/Prctl.pm#set_pdeathsig(signal)) function which takes the signal number.

Without `prctl`, a child process (which wasn't spawned by the init process and thus has a parent process ID other than 1, initially) can periodically test the value of `getppid()`. If that changes to 1, that means its original parent died.

Processes which manage children can also implement graceful shutdown logic: catch their termination signal and terminate their children as part of the cleanup. Of course, that is impossible for signals that can't be handled.

Answer (score -3):

How about the following:

```
kill( -1 * getpgid(), 9 );
```

(9 is SIGKILL: no need for macros.)

Comment: What will invoke this call if the parent dies before reaching that line of code?

Comment: @Kaz a floating hyphen can easily be overlooked. I favour `0 - getpgid`